# Перемещение картинки по нажатию клавиши

Tags: delphi

Как сделать так чтобы объект `Image1` перемещался по форме вправо при нажатии на кнопку <kbd>D</kbd>. Также чтобы держа эту кнопку объект перемещался, отпуская останавливался. Дайте пожалуйста ответ нормальный, с кодом. Я новичок и не пойму что то типа "юзай то свойство".

Answer (score 4):

1. Убедитесь, что в Инспекторе свойств (Object Inspector) отображаются свойства формы.
2. В Инспекторе свойств откройте вкладку События (Events) и найдите строчку события `OnKeyDown`.
3. Дважды кликните по текстовому полю в этой строчке. Дельфи сгенерирует код обработчика события.
4. Вставьте в качестве обработчика этот фрагмент:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
   begin
     if Key = Ord('D') then
       Shape1.Left := Shape1.Left + 1;
   end;
   ```

Comment: Вот только, мне кажется, придется еще KeyPreview := true сделать, чтобы форма первая получила сигнал нажатия клавиши, а не какой-нибудь компонент на форме.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь (лень проверять) то сработает только первый раз, для дальнейшего движения нужно отпустить кнопку.
Что не соответствует условию чтобы обьект двигался пока кнопку держишь

Comment: > (лень проверять)

Я перед тем как постить непременно проверяю код. Все отлично движется.

Comment: Да Вы правы, а одновременное нажатие клавиш обрабатывает?

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант такой
На форму бросили таймер и имедж (картинка которой управлять нужно) , двойной клик на таймере откроет код жля написания события

в него вставляем

```
 procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
if (GetKeyState (ord('D')) <0) or (GetKeyState (ord('d')) <0) then Image1.left:=Image1.left+1;
if (GetKeyState (ord('S')) <0) or (GetKeyState (ord('s')) <0) then Image1.left:=Image1.left-1;
if (GetKeyState (ord('E')) <0) or (GetKeyState (ord('e')) <0) then Image1.Top:=Image1.Top-1;
if (GetKeyState (ord('X')) <0) or (GetKeyState (ord('x')) <0) then Image1.Top:=Image1.Top+1;
image1.Repaint;
end;
```

Получаем управление картинкой клавишами S D E X
Причем зажимать можно 2 клавиши одновременно и будем перемещаться по диагонали.

Answer (score 1):

От себя добавлю лишь то, что в тех же самых событиях нужно найти `Form.Create`, а внутри написать

```
Form1.DoubleBuffered := True;
```

Тогда картинка еще и мигать не будет при смещении.

Answer (score 1):

Кидаем на форму компонент ApplicationEvents (вкладка Additional), в обработчике события OnMessage пишем:

```
if Msg.message = WM_KEYDOWN then
  case Msg.wParam of
  65: Image1.Left:=Image1.Left -1;
  68: Image1.Left:=Image1.Left +1;
  87: Image1.top:=Image1.top -1;
  83: Image1.top:=Image1.top +1;
end;
```